# Qt adding library gstreamer-1.0

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, glib, gobject

I am making a project, dependent on gstreamer-1.0, glib-2.0 and gobject-2.0.
Building in console and in VSCode works fine, but when i get to Qt, i receive the following error message:

```
:error: cannot find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/: File format not recognized
```

My .pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = Accord
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    working_directory.cpp \
    player_core.cpp \
    message.cpp

HEADERS += \
    working_directory.h \
    message.h \
    player_core.h


CONFIG += link_pkgconfig \
            c++11

PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-1.0 \
        glib-2.0 \
        gobject-2.0 \
        gio-2.0

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/ \
    /usr/include \
    /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 \
    /usr/include/glib-2.0 \
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include \
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include

LIBS += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 \
                    -lgio-2.0 \
```

Answer (score 4):

With specified *pkgconfig* should be enough. You don't need to specify the libraries independently. This might be necessary in Windows, but not in Linux. I use the next variables in Linux (Ubuntu):

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-1.0 glib-2.0 gobject-2.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-pbutils-1.0
```

If your GStreamer is in the default location it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing `QMAKE_CFLAGS_ISYSTEM = -isystem`
to `QMAKE_CFLAGS_ISYSTEM = -I`  (can be added to .pro).

for  Qt 5.10 +

Answer (score -2):

I think that `LIBS += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` is incorrect, hence the
error: `cannot find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/: File format not recognized`.

You probably meant

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

to add the directory to `ld`'s search path (although that shouldn't be necessary).